# How to add Google Map Cocoa Pod in my own Cocoa Pod Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am creating some Framework and used cocoa pods for distribution . I need to use the GoogleMap Cocoa Pod in my Framework. How will I add them.

I already add s.dependency 'GoogleMaps'  in my podspec file, but it will install the cocoa pod in the application which will use my cocoapod. How can I use GoogleMaps funtionality in my framework. I am developing it in Swift,

Answer (score -1):

This is Podfile from my older framework in which I used both private pods and public pods. Podfile should be normal like in any project you make.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace "SampleApp"
project "FrameworkName.xcodeproj"

# Private pods Spec repository
source 'https://path_to_your_private_pods'
# Public spec repository
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target :FrameworkName do
    xcodeproj "FrameworkName.xcodeproj"

   // PUBLIC PODS 
   pod 'GoogleMaps'

   // PRIVATE PODS 
   pod 'PrivatePod', :git => 'git@path_to_your_private_pod', :branch => 'branch-name'
end
```

(You can update it to newer sintax)

Also, you must create podspec file in which you will define your depencencies:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name             = 'SampleApp'
  spec.version          = '0.1.0'
  spec.license          = { :type => 'BSD' }
  spec.homepage         = 'http://www....'
  spec.authors          = { 'Author' => 'Email' }
  spec.summary          = 'Summary'
  spec.source           = { :git => 'https://PATH_TO_REPOSITORY', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  spec.source_files     = 'SampleApp'
  spec.requires_arc     = true
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  spec.resources        = ["some_path_to_resources/*.png"]

  spec.dependency 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Podspec spec.dependency part IS THE MOST IMPORTANT becouse from it all your framework dependencies will be read.

Comment: I did the same in podspec file , my question is how to use the google maps inside my own framework. Lets say my framework is Utility I want to give maps funtonlity in my framework. So I need to write some code in my framework using Google Maps. But how would I add them ?

Comment: You can use all of the Google Maps framework functionality ... it wont be buildable because dependencies are added when the framework is installed (you must first add your framework to your project as a pod for example, and in that moment google maps pod will be installed) but all of the functionality should be there ...

Comment: So You mean to say I need to add podfile in which I need to define GoogleMap dependency in my framework first

Comment: 1) you add podfile with google map dependency to your framework 2) you add podspec file that defines also that dependency 3) you write your framework (it wont be buildable because dependencies are added in the later stage) 4) you add your framework to real project with cocoapods for example which is in that moment buildable and usable ... hope i'm clear now

Comment: One last thing when I added the pod install in my sample project it shows no GoogleMaps found because its source files are not imported in framework

Comment: are you using google maps cocoa pod or you are using static library (drag and drop it into project)?

Comment: Google Cocoapod

Comment: hm ... it should work then ... so once again are projectname.podspec and podfile in your framework root folder? (podspec MUST HAVE this line   spec.dependency 'GOOGLEMAPSFRAMEWORKNAME') Does framework have projectname.xcworkspace project file? did you create pod from you framework (do you import it in some podfile with pod 'frameworkname') ? If all of this is true can you write exactly error which is displayed?

Comment: When I install my framework using cocoa pods, it shows , Google Maps not found.

Comment: its not working ! Can you please tell me any otherwork around if possible

Comment: @ManiaChamp Did you found any solution for this issue?